# How to use winston@3.0.0 for winston-azure-blob-transport?

Tags: node.js, winston

I am using **winston-azure-blob-transport** for my Node.js app hosted on azure app service so I can write logs to blog storage. I am getting following warnings on the console

```
BlobTransport is a legacy winston transport. Consider upgrading: 
console.pub.js:42
- Upgrade docs: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md
```

this tells me I need to upgrade the version to 3.x but, I am already on `winston": "^3.1.0"`

So why do I get waring? And what do I do about it? If I need to make a change how can I make it on my app with NPM install?

Also, I am using code mentioned under 'Usage' section from [BlobTransport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-azure-blob-transport) so if I update to 3.0.0 what code I should be using for Node.js?

My code

```
var logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new(winston.transports.AzureBlob)({
            account: {
                name: 'abc',
                key: 'abc'
            },
            containerName: 'applicationlogs',
            blobName: 'info.log',
            level: 'info'
        })
]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

this one is compatible, it's inspirated by winston-azure-blob-transport

https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston3-azureblob-transport

Answer (score 0):

You can create customTransport using "[winston-transport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-transport)" and "[Azure Storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-storage)" for Winston 3 and above.